# PHP & MySQL - Identify table in results from joined tables

Tags: php, mysql

Say you have the following query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cars LEFT JOIN trucks WHERE cars.user_id=$user_id AND trucks.user_id=$user_id";
```

Since for my page `cars` and `trucks` have different layouts how do I know what result belongs to what table ? They are basically the same but with different table names.

How do I retrieve the table names ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what abut using alias and `table-name.column-name` ?

Answer (score 1):

All columns on the left will belong to left table i.e. cars and all to the right would be truck.

So for e.g. if i have table like cars(id..) and truck(id..)

Then output would be

```
id...(from cars) id..(from truck)
```

If you want specific columns then use something like:

```
SELECT `truck`.id,`cars`.id...
```

Comment: But how do I know what's the table? like echo $sql->vehicle_id ..... how do I retrieve the table name?

Comment: In case `vehicle_id` is common in both `cars` and `trucks` then in the query you have to change it `SELECT cars.vehicle_id, trucks.vehicle_id FROM cars LEFT JOIN trucks WHERE cars.user_id=$user_id AND trucks.user_id=$user_id ;`  as mentioned in the answer by SMA

Comment: @MySQLRockstar But in PHP, ¿How do I know what table is the result from? -- I'd like to retrieve the table like $thetable = $sql->vehicle_id.TABLE; so it would tell me if it's "cars" or "trucks"